# Geoserver getfeatureinfo returns big number with exponential format

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, getfeatureinfo

I have a Geoserver layer, which contains numbers on a million scale in one of the attributes.

If I query these features, I get back a number in this format: 4.1E7 instead of this: 410000000

Is there a workaround or setting for this?

I use PostgreSQL 9.3 as a backend, and it is a Geoserver 2.4.2.

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the getFeatureInfo [template](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/#advanced-formating) used by geoserver, see section "Advanced Formatting". You could try to intercept the ${attribute.rawValue} and print this directly or modify it before sending the feature info back.

Comment: Thank you @tareq, it totally solved my issue! And BTW, can I use all freemarker "Buildt-in"-s in my template to format my rawValue? http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_quickstart_template.html#autoid_7

Comment: I am not too familiar with the templating in geoserver. You could try, which fits best for you and post here, what you did.